# Send server side requests for routes to VueJS 2

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

If you create a new application (with router support) using Vue CLI 3 and launch the built in development server (with npm run serve or yarn serve depending on your preference), you can go to, for example, the created /about route directly in your browser and it will load.

Behind the scenes, something in the built in development server must be taking the request and routing it to the vue router. I'd like to find out what that is.

Now that I've finished developing my app (https://github.com/insprintorob/libre) I'd like to replicate this functionality in my own express server.

However, if I go to, for example /about when my static site app is being served statically using express, it will give you a 404 error because that route isn't registered with express.

How is the vue-cli setup allowing you to go to routes directly and how can I replicate that with express?

Answer (score 1):

> Behind the scenes, something in the built in development server must
>   be taking the request and routing it to the vue router.

The router handles the pages on the client side, where each route is associated with one view. The view is just a component that represents a "page". The router allows the creation of Single Page Applications.

[Learn more](https://router.vuejs.org/)

```
// 1. Define route components.
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

// 2. Define some routes
// Each route should map to a component.
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

// 3. Create the router instance and pass the `routes` option
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

// 4. Inject the router with the router option on the root instance.
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```